# CRM 2011: Save passive entity using javascript

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

Is there a way to perform save using javascript for an entity that is passive? I'm trying to use `Xrm.Page.data.entity.save()`, but because entity is passive nothing happens.

Comment: for passive, you mean inactive record?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out this by myself.

I used `SDK.REST.updateRecord()` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334427.aspx) to update my entity. Then inside successCallback function I run `window.location.reload(true)` in order to simulate page reload that happens when saving.